# Website database issue... [PHP, MySQLi, HTML]

Tags: php, html, database

So I am working on this under construction page for my own small business's website. I want to have an email field so that users write their email so that i can later tell them when the page is finished. But I am having trouble with the database. Apparently the connection is established but the data is not being written to the table in the DB. This is my php code, it is embedded on the top of my index.html:

```
    <?php require 'connections/connections.php'; ?>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $Fname = $_POST['first_name'];
            $Lname = $_POST['last_name'];
            $Email = $_POST['email'];

            $sql = $con->query("INSER INTO subscriptions (Fname, Lname, Email)Values('{$Fname}', '{$Lname}', '{$Email}')");

            header ('Location: confirm.html');

        }



?>
```

This is my connections.php file, required by the above code:

```
    <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "webmaster_velez", "Cristianpromw3", "nexus_subscriptions");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

This is the HTML that the user interacts with to send their email address:

```
        <div id="subscribe">
            <form id="SubscriptionForm" name="RegisterForm" method="post">
                <div class="FormElement">
                    <input name="first_name" type="text" required="required" class="TField" id="first_name" form="SubscriptionForm" placeholder="First Name">
                </div>
                <div class="FormElement">
                    <input name="last_name" type="text" required="required" class="TField" id="last_name" form="SubscriptionForm" placeholder="Last Name">
                 </div>
                <div class="FormElement">
                    <input name="email" type="email" required="required" class="TField" id="email" form="SubscriptionForm" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                  <div class="FormElement">
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" id="submit" form="SubscriptionForm" value="Submit">
                  </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Any help, corrections, and/or advice on this would be much appreciated and accepted. Thanks in advance.

PS. I am new to PHP and database/server dynamics.

Comment: "INSER INTO" is probably part of the problem, if not the problem

Comment: You have a typo… and an SQL injection vulnerability in your SQL statement.

Comment: Also, do some error checking on your execute of the query, it would've told you what went wrong.

Comment: OMG is this serious lol!! let me correct that spelling error...

Comment: @MartinBean what do you mean by a SQL injection vulnerability? how can I resolve it?

Comment: @Cristian Velez You’re passing the values of $_POST variables directly to your statement. A nefarious user can modify your SQL statement to drop your databases and other malicious commands. You need to sanitise _any_ user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the code you've written, I would assume that the main problem you are facing is this typo - `"INSER INTO"` should be `"INSERT INTO"`.

You'll also need to implement some try error blocks to catch if any errors are happening and protect yourself from SQL vulnerabilities/injections.

Comment: I have corrected this typo and now it is working fine. How can I make this security improvements?

Comment: Prepare your sql statements, it'll be in the documentation :) If this answer has helped you please mark as accepted :)